# Build the tree hierarchy of apps in Coded UI test for windows phone without manually building the UIMap

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone, coded-ui-tests

I was looking for automation testing tools for Windows Phone like `adb` for Android or `iOS instruments` for iOS. I have found `Coded UI Test`. That works fine if you want to build your test on a subset of UI elements.

But I need to build the list of all UI elements dynamically, or rather I need to know the hierarchical tree of the window with which the user interacts (something similar to `logElementTree` in `iOS instruments`) during the test.

I wouldn't build UIMap for every page of my app. Instead I'd prefer to build the hierarchical tree of `UIElements` dynamically in order to find the element of interest (such as an object for a tap action) by its properties (name, text, bounds, etc.).

For example, to give you an idea, I would like to do something like this pseudo code:

```
listOfUIObjects = getWindowTree(app);

element=listOfUIObjects.getElementByText("Pippo");

element.tap();
```

Does someone of you know a way to do this with `coded ui test`?
If it's not possible, is there an automation tool to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't grab a 'tree' as such, but you can search for controls programatically. Take a look here for a starter:
http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/04/10/programmatically-use-of-coded-ui-in-visual-studio/

Another good place to look is the generated code behind a UI map - it will show you the search code used which you should be able to modify for your own uses.